# Showing ${Z}\left [ d \right ]=\left \{ a+b\sqrt{d}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \right \}$ is an integral domain

Tags: ring-theory

> question:
>
> Show that $\mathbb{Z}\left [ d \right ]=\left \{ a+b\sqrt{d}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \right \}$ is an integral domain.

By definition, an integral domain is a commutative ring with unity containing no zero-divisor. What is strange is that in my solution sheet, the sufficient condition is to show that $\mathbb{Z}\left [ d \right ]=\left \{ a+b\sqrt{d}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \right \}$ is an integral domain is a subring.

Why is showing the above a subring sufficient?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "is an integral domain is a subring" I'm not sure what that means. And a subring of _which_ ring?

Answer (score 1):

What is really important is a subring **of what**. In this case it is trivial to see the given ring is a subring of $\;\Bbb R\;$ (assuming $\;d\ge0\;$ . If $\;d<0\;$ then it is a subring of $\;\Bbb C\;$ ), a field, and thus it is an integral domain.

Comment: Would it be equally valid, though tedious, to verify that the above is a commutative ring containing no zero divisor?

Comment: @Mathematicing Of course, and it wouldn't be that tedious in fact. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

A subring **of an integral domain** is always an integral domain -- since if $ab=0$ in the subring with $a,b$ both nonzero, the same would be the case in the larger integral domain, which we know it isn't.

Therefore since $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ is a subring of $\mathbb C$ (which is a field and therefore in particular an integral domain) it is an integral domain.